# Usage of the word Found

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please explain me the difference in usage of the word 'found' and phrase 'found out'?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Context, please. Words mean virtually nothing without context.

Comment: *Found* is simply the past tense of [*find*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/find#Verb), while *found out* is simply the past tense of [*find out*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/find_out#Verb).

Comment: Or, are you talking about the verb ["to found"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/found)?

Answer (score 1):

*Found* is simply the past tense of *find*. 'Found out' is synonymous with *discovered*.